# python and function argument

Tags: python, post, get, python-requests

I have simple code for auth via post request.
Server an every request generates "javax.faces.ViewState" variable
like javax.faces.ViewState=123456784356754

```
import requests
import re


global_headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0',
                   'Accept': 'application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01',
                   'Referer': 'http://serrver.com/login/'}

req = requests.Session(headers=global_headers)

def javalue_parser():
        javalue = re.findall(r'name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="(.*?)"')
        print javalue[0]
        return javalue



my_post_req = req.post('http://server.com/login/',
                 data={'phone': '+11(123)456-78-91', 
                       'loginForm': 'loginForm',
                       'javax.faces.ViewState': "%s" % javalue_parser()
                        })
```

I always have error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rework_sms.py", line 28, in <module>
    'javax.faces.ViewState': "%s" % javalue_parser()
  File "test.py", line 19, in javalue_parser
    javalue = re.findall(r'name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="(.*?)"')
TypeError: findall() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

What's argument needed?

Comment: *What* do you want to find using the regex *from*? That's the other argument.

Comment: Some digits like 12344556, but i can't execute function in post request

If i use javalue_parser(my_post_req.content) it working fine

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the documentation of [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall)

> re.findall(pattern, **string**, flags=0)
>   Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern **in string**, as a list of
>   strings. **The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found**. If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of another match.